# Trying to Find YOY Percent Change and Group By two Criteria in Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my setup.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[110,2020,'CHASE CENTER',53901,8904,44997,4], 
        [110,2019,'CHASE CENTER',57999,4921,53078,1], 
        [110,2018,'CHASE CENTER',91015,9945,81070,1], 
        [640,2020,'LAMBEAU WI',76214,5773,70441,3], 
        [619,2020,'SAL AIRPORT',93000,8278,84722,5]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Location', 'Year', 'Location_Description', 'Revenue', 'Spend', 'Profit_Or_Loss', 'cluster_number'])
df.dtypes


df['YOY_Percent_Change'] = df.groupby(['Location','Year'])['Profit_Or_Loss'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).subtract(1).mul(100))
df
```

I want to get the Year Over Year Percent Change in 'Profit_Or_Loss' and Group By location and Year, descending, but I'm getting all zeros.

[image]

I found this function, but it changes for every record.

```
df['YOY_Percent_Change'] = df['Profit_Or_Loss'].pct_change(1)
```

I want the calculation to reset when there is a new 'Location'. I would really like to end up with something like this.

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('Location')['Profit_Or_Loss'].pct_change().round(2).fillna(0)` ?

Comment: Why is the YOY % change in reverse order or year ?   Just some toy figures or deliberate ?

Comment: @ Scott Boston, that looks legit, but I'm still getting all zeros when I run your code. I just checked 'Profit_or_Loss' and I see that it is a float64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df['YOY_Percent_Change'] = (df.groupby('Location')['Profit_Or_Loss']
                              .pct_change()
                              .round(2)
                              .fillna(0)
                              .mul(100).astype(int).astype(str) + '%')
```

Output:

```
   Location  Year Location_Description  Revenue  Spend  Profit_Or_Loss  cluster_number YOY_Percent_Change
0       110  2020         CHASE CENTER    53901   8904           44997               4                 0%
1       110  2019         CHASE CENTER    57999   4921           53078               1                18%
2       110  2018         CHASE CENTER    91015   9945           81070               1                53%
3       640  2020           LAMBEAU WI    76214   5773           70441               3                 0%
4       619  2020          SAL AIRPORT    93000   8278           84722               5                 0%
```